# In the child_process module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In the `child_process` module in node.js, why `execSync ('node.exe --version')` can get the value, and `spawnSync ('node.exe', ['--version'])` can not get the value? But `childProcess.spawnSync ('D: / Program Files / nodejs / node.exe', ['--version']);` can get the value.

Comment: In fact this is the problem that causes my **vscode** to fail to work properly.Because **vscode** in many use `spawnSync()` function.

Comment: **This question ware resolved.** see [#728](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/728)

Answer (score 1):

`exec` use the system bash, and `spawn` is implement by `fork` in *nix (createProcess in windows.h, I guess).

Comment: why `childProcess.spawnSync ('D:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe', ['--version']);` can get the value?

Comment: @JRoger when you use command `'node.exe'`, system will search the local  work dir, if not found then system will search the `node.exe` from `$PATH` directory *go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) for more info*. And `bash` may load the config, such as `.bashrc`, by default so that system can found it found from a `$PATH`. While you use command `'D:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe'` it mean a full path, system don't need to search from `$PATH`.

Comment: Lellansin    path `D:/Program Files/nodejs/` ware in my computer's environment variable.

Comment: As I say, it maybe cause by the implement. `exec` use the system bash, so that will search in $PATH, but `spawn` does not.

Comment: @Lellansini   not what you said. see [#728](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/728)

Comment: I got it. your question is more simple than what I answer. I got wrong direction about your problem. I tried to see the source code of node.js, the spawn function, just accept spawn(file, args, ...) as arguments, but what you pass is spawn(file + args, ...)

Comment: please look carefully `childProcess.spawnSync ('D:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe', ['--version']);`. -_-||

Comment: Thanks for your answer.